# Issue in saving the content of a dataframe to table

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a data source (hive external tables) which refresh the data in adhoc manner. To avoid any discrepancies in the execution i'm trying to save the data as a table in my location.

Initially, i have loaded the data from data source to a dataframe

```
source = hqlContext.table("datasourcedb.table1") // this is working fine
```

Then, trying to save it the my application location -

```
  source.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable("appdb.table1")  //No read/write operations on appdb.table1 while doing this action
```

Above actions throwing exceptions:

```
java.io.IOException: The file being written is in an invalid state. Probably caused by an error thrown previously. Current state: BLOCK
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter$STATE.error(ParquetFileWriter.java:146)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter$STATE.startBlock(ParquetFileWriter.java:138)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.startBlock(ParquetFileWriter.java:195)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:153)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:113)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:112)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetRelation.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.abortTask$1(WriterContainer.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/03/02 04:31:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 9 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
18/03/02 04:31:32 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
```

**Note: The size of the source is abot 6GB. Hence, no persist action is planned **

Comment: I think the error message is clear: **java.io.IOException: The file being written is in an invalid state. Probably caused by an error thrown previously. Current state: BLOCK**  You have to unblock (probably make it consistent).  You are missing **key** part of information and that is to what filesystem you are writing.  Do you run out-of-memory by any chance?